# How can I store 4 radio buttons with 4 each colors to my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have 4 radio buttons and they have 1 color each when a user selects a radio button with a color it display it in a table cell. When the user clicks on submit it saves the info to my database, so the user can have the exact same options when they come back to the website.

I removed the details to the database connection just so you know.

I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

```
$first = $_POST['white'];
$first = $_POST['red'];
$first = $_POST['orange'];
$first = $_POST['green'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO savecolor (white, red, orange, green) VALUES ('$first')";
```

I might have messed these up. I don't really know.^^

```
<form action="include/dbh.inc.php" method="post">
<table id="table">
    <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="white">
                    <input type="radio" name="first" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
                    </div>
                <div class="red">
                    <input type="radio" name="first" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
                    </div>
                <div class="orange">
                    <input type="radio" name="first" value="orange" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
                </div>
                <div class="green">
                    <input type="radio" name="first" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)"> 
                </div>
            <br>
            This is a text.
</td>
```

php code

```
<?php

$dbServername = "";
$dbUsername = "";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "";

   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if(!$conn){
echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}

$first = $_POST['white'];
$first = $_POST['red'];
$first = $_POST['orange'];
$first = $_POST['green'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO savecolor (white, red, orange, green) VALUES('$first')";

if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
echo 'Not Inserted';
}
else
{
 echo 'Inserted';
}
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It should rather be `$first = $_POST['first'];` The color is a value not the name. The same goes for your DB columns. Keep one column called `color` and store the value of the selected color in there.

Comment: what have i done wrong with this php code should i just erase it? im lost and i know of the sql injections people can do. this is only gonna be avaible to my teacher when its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the value, you need to use input's name attribute.

And you should use mysqli_real_escape_string for security. [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);

//Not $first = $_POST['first']
//Or not $first = $_POST['white'];
```

Now you need to insert this to your database. Your database should hold only choosen color.

> You don't need columns like red, white, orange, green
>
> You just need a column like user_color

After re-building your database, let's insert it.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO savecolor (user_color) VALUES ('$first')");
//Check it
if ($query) {
   echo 'Inserted';
} else {
   echo 'Not Inserted';
}
```

Note:

You should check post before everything.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST)) {
    //There is no post so exit.
    exit(0);
}
....
```

Comment: tried it and it doesnt show anything in my database. i get the message not inserted???

Comment: @pleasehelpme Can you add this  `echo mysqli_error($conn);` below `echo 'Not Inserted';`

Comment: now i get InsertedTable 'dbname.savecolor' doesn't exist.   

dbname is the database name

Comment: @pleasehelpme Are you sure that you have a table called 'savecolor' in dbname?

Comment: Yup the table is named savecolor and then i have id & user_color or em i retarded and messed everything up in phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @pleasehelpme can you send a screenshot of phpmyadmin

Comment: i dunno how to upload picture so i used gyazo isntead
https://gyazo.com/ffaaf4d104bd62ba813f215ffe58fdfe

Comment: @pleasehelpme are you sure that table's name is savecolor?

Comment: its working now but its not showing what color the user made as seen?
https://gyazo.com/307835dd748e5c0c1f9ca1f8fa5d9128

Comment: @pleasehelpme can you upload a screenshot of your php file

Comment: well well it does show the color now. I have 9 tables with 4 radiobuttons each and yes i only showed 1 table row with 4 button when i made this post. i think i found the problem why its only showing 1 color in phpmyadmin but i dunno really how to do it. i tried my thing but didnt work the page end up blank.
https://gyazo.com/6fb7cdf3d395d6871d10146088f59a05

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the SQL Injections warning in the comments. Learn how to use prepared statements and make it a habit.

In the query `$sql = "INSERT INTO savecolor (white, red, orange, green) VALUES('$first')";` it is trying to populate 4 columns, but only supplying one value.

You might consider changing the layout of the `savecolor` table to only hold one variable `colorchoice` or something like that. Then you would only need to insert `$_POST['first']` into that table (after you change the query to use prepared statements :).